# HTML Img's failing to load

Tags: javascript, html, image

Just for fun, i'm trying to implement a "15 puzzle", but with 16 images (from 1 music photo) instead.

The thing is split into 2 scripts / sides. 1 Python CGI script that will perform the Last.FM query + splitting the image in Y x Z chunks. When the python script finishes it outputs a JSON string that contains the location (on server), extension etc.

```
{"succes": true, "content": {"nrofpieces": 16, "size": {"width": 1096, "height": 961}, "directoryname": "Mako", "extension": "jpeg"}}
```

On the other side is a HTML, JS, (CSS) combo that will query the CGI script for the images.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var artiest = $("#artiest")
var rijen = $("#rijen")
var kolommen = $("#kolommen")
var speelveld = $("#speelveld")
var search = $("#search")


$("#buttonClick").click(function () {
    var artiestZ = artiest.val()
    var rijenZ = rijen.val()
    var kolommenZ = kolommen.val()

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/cgiScript.py", "artiest=" + artiestZ + "&rijen=" + rijenZ + "&kolommen=" + kolommenZ, function (JsonSring) {
        console.log("HIIIIII")
        if (JsonSring.succes === true){
            console.log(JsonSring)
            var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/"
            var extension = JsonSring.content.extension
            var url = baseUrl + JsonSring.content.directoryname + "/"
            var amountX = rijenZ 
            var amountY = kolommenZ 

            for (var i = 0; i < amountX; i += 1){
                for (var p = 0; p < amountY; p += 1){
                    console.log("HI")
                    var doc = new Image
                    doc.setAttribute("src", url + JsonSring.content.directoryname + i + "_" + p + "." +extension)
                    document.getElementById("speelveld").appendChild(doc)
                }
            }
        }else {
            // Search failed. Deal with it.
        }
    })
})
```

})

where the various id's link to various HTML elements. (Text Fields & Buttons & Div's).

Beneath is a screenshot of the full folder that contains the image files.

[image: Folder with IMG files]

Now, coming to the point. All the HTML img tags with src seem correct, yet. Some images don't load, yet other do. I also noticed that all images failed to load in 2s intervals. Is there some kind of timeout, or so?

[image: Result]

All this is being ran from a local machine, so disk speed and cpu shouldn't really affect the matter. Also, from what I understand: The call for making the img tags etc is done in a callback from the getJson, meaning it'll only run when getJson has finished / had a reply.

Does the great StackOverFlow community have an idea what's happening here?

Comment: how many concurrent connections are configured on server's side?

Comment: @Lashane : This is all the code I use for the server side. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/deca2c05f14d781f851979d74581f6dd

Comment: Am I reading your network graph correctly - each image takes 12.9s to load? That is ridiculously long on a local web server. There seems to be some congestion on the files. Maybe the Python script saves them asynchronously, or otherwise maintains a lock on them. See what happens if you temporarily disable that part of your code.

Comment: @Ruud : Well I just tried disabling the part of the code that makes A. a new folder and B. chop's the images up into bits. Therefor now I rely on the previously (already process) image bits. Still having connection refused's.

Comment: Could be your local webserver is misconfigured; what are you using, Apache, IIS? Have you tried different web browsers? Try undressing your application even further; does the same problem occur on a static HTML page with IMG tags (as opposed to JavaScript creating the image objects)? What is the _minimal_ reproducible situation?

Comment: @Ruud : I was using something in the neighborhood of  ```python -m CGIHTTPServer```, but recently due to problems with the Allow Origin headers, i've begun using http.server -cgi for the cgi server. It now works. I'm assuming the CGIHTTPServer package only had 1 object handling the load etc, and therefor it couldn't process all the requests in time. PS: Do I need to add how I "fixed" it to the post?

Comment: Please update your question with details about the problematic web server, and create a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the solution. I really think this is a valuable experience and deserves its place in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share my knowledge/experiences with the great StackOverflow community,

## Small backstory

After progressing a bit further into the project I started to run into various issues going from JSON parsing to not having `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` headers, making it very hard to get the Ajax Request (Client ==> Python CGI) done.

In the meantime I also started dev'ing on my main desktop (which for some reason either has massive issues with Python versioning or has none). But due to the terminal on my desktop having Python 3.4+ , there was no module CGIHTTPServer. After a small amount of digging, I found that CGIHTTPServer had been transfered into http.server, yet when running plain old `python -m http.server`, I noticed the CGI script wouldn't run. It would just display. Ofcourse, I forgot the option `-cgi`.

## Main solution

The times I was succesfully using CGIHTTPServer, I had troubles. The images wouldn't load as described above. I suspect that the module just couldn't take the decent amount of requests. Meaning that when suddenly Y x Z requests came in, it would struggle to deliver all the data. ==> Connection Refused.

Since switching to `python -m http.server -cgi`, no problems what so ever. Currently working on a Bootstrap Grid for all those images!

Thx @Lashane and @Ruud.